# Docker image deploys successfully to ACR, but Web API wont run

Tags: c#, azure, docker, azure-container-registry

I have the following `work flow` file within `GitHub` action, this `work flow` file creates a docker image from my `Web API` project and uploads to `Azure Container Registry`

```
name: Build and Deploy Docker Image to Azure Container Registry
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - feature/api-dev
env:
  REGISTRY: registryURL.azurecr.io
  IMAGE_NAME: my_web_api
  AZURE_SERVICE_PRINCIPAL: ${{ secrets.AZURE_SERVICE_PRINCIPAL }}
  AZURE_SERVICE_PRINCIPAL_PASSWORD: ${{ secrets.AZURE_SERVICE_PRINCIPAL_PASSWORD }}
  AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION_ID: ${{ secrets.AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION_ID }}
  AZURE_RESOURCE_GROUP: MY-RESOURCE-GROUP
  AZURE_WEBAPP_PACKAGE_PATH: ./publish
  DOCKERFILE_PATH: ./Project.STT.API/Dockerfile
  
defaults:
  run:
    working-directory: ./Project.STT.API/
    
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
     
      - name: Setup .NET Core
        uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v3
        with:
          dotnet-version: 7.x
                
      - name: Restore
        run: dotnet restore Project.STT.API.sln
     
      - name: Build
        run: dotnet build Project.STT.API.sln --configuration Release --no-restore
     
      - name: Publish
        run: dotnet publish Project.STT.API.sln --configuration Release --no-build
          --output '${{ env.AZURE_WEBAPP_PACKAGE_PATH }}'
     
      - name: Login to Azure
        uses: azure/login@v1
        with:
          creds: ${{ secrets.AZURE_SERVICE_PRINCIPAL }}

      - name: Set up Docker Buildx
        uses: docker/setup-buildx-action@v2

      - name: Azure Docker Login
        uses: azure/docker-login@v1
        with:
          login-server: ${{ secrets.REGISTRY_LOGIN_SERVER }}
          username: ${{ secrets.REGISTRY_USERNAME }}
          password: ${{ secrets.REGISTRY_PASSWORD }}

      - name: Build Docker image v2
        uses: docker/build-push-action@v2
        with:
          context: .
          file: ${{ env.DOCKERFILE_PATH }}
          push: true
          tags: ${{ secrets.REGISTRY_LOGIN_SERVER }}/registryName:latest
          # outputs: type=registry        
      
      - name: Deploy to Azure Container Instances
        uses: azure/aci-deploy@v1
        with:
          resource-group: ${{ secrets.RESOURCE_GROUP }}
          dns-name-label: ${{ secrets.RESOURCE_GROUP }}${{ github.run_number }}
          image: ${{ secrets.REGISTRY_LOGIN_SERVER }}/registryName:latest
          registry-login-server: ${{ secrets.REGISTRY_LOGIN_SERVER }}
          registry-username: ${{ secrets.REGISTRY_USERNAME }}
          registry-password: ${{ secrets.REGISTRY_PASSWORD }}
          name: aci-webapi
          location: australiaeast
      
      - name: Logout from Azure
        run: docker logout ${{ env.REGISTRY }}
```

The docker file:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:7.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:7.0 AS build
COPY . .
RUN dotnet restore "./Project.STT.API/Project.STT.API.csproj"
RUN dotnet build "./Project.STT.API/Project.STT.API.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "./Project.STT.API/Project.STT.API.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=false

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Project.STT.API.dll"]
```

This `work flow` runs and pushing the image to `Azure Container Registry` successfully, now the problem is. When I try to build an `App Service` from said `Docker Image` I constantly get

> :( Application Error If you are the application administrator, you can
> access the diagnostic resources.

When viewing the diagnostic resource, I'm unable to see any logs or errors.

I then decided to build an `App Service` from the image within `Azure Container Registry`, and the same error occurs which makes me think it's to do with the `Docker Image`, however, as this `Docker Image` is created successfully from the `GitHub Workflow File` I'm unsure how I can track down the error.  Has anyone experienced this before? if so, what would be the best way to tackle this?

I did make sure both `App Services` were on the `Linux` operation system to make the project configuration.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need some logs to get the exact error that you have. Try to host this container on your local machine (docker desktop or podman), then try to read the logs.
If the application crash on start to get the logs you have to get the container id then it's logs:

```
docker ps -a
docker logs [container-id]
```

Comment: correct, I've tried to run / build it locally, but I keep getting failed to solve: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = read AppData\Local\Docker\backend.lock: The process cannot access the file because another process has locked a portion of the file.

Comment: sorry, but you have tried to build in your machine and you are getting this error?
Don't do a new build, just use the image pushed on your Azure Container Registry. So configure your private container registry, and pull from there. Doing like this you are testing the same version that you are trying to release

Comment: Another thing that has nothing to do with your issue, but it's just an optimization: cause you are doing the dotnet build and publish into your Dockerfile, it's useless to do it also outside of it in the body of your pipeline. So below steps in your pipeline can be skipped: - name: Setup .NET Core
- name: Restore
- name: Build
- name: Publish

Comment: It seems to be pulling and running locally, 

This is what I see in logs from Docker
2023-07-25 08:11:17 info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[14]
2023-07-25 08:11:17       Now listening on: http://[::]:80
2023-07-25 08:11:17 info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
2023-07-25 08:11:17       Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
2023-07-25 08:11:17 info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
2023-07-25 08:11:17       Hosting environment: Production
2023-07-25 08:11:17 info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
2023-07-25 08:11:17       Content root path: /app

But I can't find the URL??

Comment: tried docker run -p 8080:80 bd90a49377e5 when visiting http://localhost:8080/swagger/index.html I get This localhost page can’t be found No web page was found for the web address: http://localhost:8080/swagger/index.html

Comment: Have you tried to access swagger from inside the container? Try to enter with docker exec -it container_name and then run wget localhost/swagger/index.html to see if something happens. If it works, it should be only be a problem of port exposure or network configuration